# Sub directory as GET with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to use "fake" sub-directories as GET requests. Sorry for my inaccurate wording.

I current have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pggr/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

So `http://example.com/pggr/blah` is treated as `http://example.com/?p=blah`.

However I want to remove the `pggr` part from the url, so it would be just `http://example.com/blah`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Excellent sir! Works perfectly.

Comment: I yes I know, I just needed to wait some five minutes to accept it and then left.